# Issue with javax.mail.internet.AddressException:Domain contains illegal character in string

Tags: email, jakarta-mail

I have been going through a lot of questions regarding the `javax.mail.internet.AddressException` and from what I have noticed, the email id format is responsible for this exception to be thrown.
I have encountered this problem and I have not been to able to get to the root of it.
My question is, what is the exact reason for this Exception to be thrown? 
Also, will it be thrown if the mail address is of the form `someThing.another@someName.com`?

Here is the log:
``` methodName: Exception while processing the Mail Body javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Domain contains illegal character in string ``'help@xyz.com''' ```

Comment: go through this for details about AddressException http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/internet/AddressException.html

Comment: getRef(),getPos() methods of this exception will help you in finding while parsing what value error came and at what position.

Comment: Same exception here when parsing a message with such single quotes in To: MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session, emlFileInputStream); String to = parseAddresses(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)); How to fix To before parsing to avoid exception?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your address contains quote characters.  It should not.

Where is the address coming from?  Is it coded as a Java String constant in your application?  Is it being read from a database?  Read from a user input field?

Comment: You mean this address `'help@xyz.com'`? It is taken from the database.

Comment: Yes, based on the error message you posted, the address literally contains those quote characters.  The address should be simply help@xyz.com, without any quote characters.  Perhaps someone mistakenly added the quote characters when typing it in and adding it to the database?  If all the addresses in your database are of that form, you might need to strip off the incorrect quote characters before using the addresses.

Comment: Well, I have added those quotes in the above comment, I am not sure if the quotes appear elsewhere it is used.
Is it possible to tell that by looking at the exception I have posted in the question?

Comment: Yes.  See how the exception has three sets of single quotes around the address, and two of the three on the left are backquotes?  The inner single quotes are actually part of the address string, which is why it is failing.